# My finger eraser delete my bitmap in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

i have coded a drawing activity but when i select the eraser, this one erase my bitmap. I have searched but no solutions are coming to me ^^.

Thanks in advance for your help

THis is where it's coded :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(scaledBm, 14), 0, 0, paint);

    if(eraserOn == 1){
        for (Map.Entry<Path, String> entry : ModificationActivity.pathsList.entrySet()) {
            Path cle = entry.getKey();
            String valeur = entry.getValue();
            int myColor = Color.parseColor(valeur);
            paint.setColor(myColor);
            //path = cle;
        }
    }else{
        paint.setAlpha(0xFF);//transperent color
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

ultimately you want some kind of scratch effect on your image.
Have a look at [this](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView) library.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

**Steps:**

You can download and modify the source of library.you just need to put your image instead of Red color.so it will feel like you are erasing the image.

I hope it will be helpful !!